# password protection for a zip file is not working

Tags: php, zip

```
 My php version : 5.4.6
```

This is my code. After excecuting this i got an erroe

```
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $code = $zip->open('zipfiles/test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
   if ($code === true)
    echo 'zip opened<br>';
   else
    echo $code.'<br>';
   $zip->addFile('test.jpg');

   $code = $zip->setPassword('secret');

   if ($code === true)
     echo 'password set<br>';
   else
     echo $code.'<br>';

   $code = $zip->close();
   if ($code === true)
    echo 'closed<br>';
   else
    echo $code.'<br>';

   echo 'done<br>';
```

But i got an error that

```
   Fatal error: Call to undefined method ZipArchive::setPassword() in D:\xampp\htdocs\zipfile.php on line 25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php) says you need php 5.6.0 or higher.
You have 5.4.6. So you need to upgrade your php install.

You can find the function setPassword() at the bottom of the [list of new functions added in PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-functions.php).

Answer (score 2):

"setPassword" does not work in this case.
This function only sets the password to be used to decompress the archive; it does not turn a non-password-protected ZipArchive into a password-protected ZipArchive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11915741)

Comment: @devlincarnate & other reviewers. Read the question again. This IS an answer to it. (If it is a wrong answer, that is a different issue.)

Comment: @Mogsdad -  It only states what is wrong, not how to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not saying this answer is good / bad or right / wrong - only that it constitutes _an answer_. A bad answer is still an answer. Bad answers can be downvoted & deleted, but flags should be reserved for things that are not answers, or cannot be salvaged to be answers.

Comment: @Mogsdad - I guess we disagree on what constitutes an answer.  Merely stating the problem is not the same thing as offering a solution.  An answer is an attempt at resolving the problem.  This makes no such attempt.